# JSON to EXCEL using VBA without external GitHub project or Power Query

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am trying to import a json file to EXCEL using VBA code but I neither want to use a GitHub project nor use Power Query but I am not able to get any proper reference on how to do it. The json string looks like this:

```
{
    "menu": "food",
    "open": "true",
    "order": "true",
    "food": [
        {
            "name": "burger",
            "type": "saucy",
            "id": 1,
            "available": true,
            "price": "3$"
        },
        {
            "name": "pizza",
            "type": "spicy",
            "id": 2,
            "available": true,
            "price": "2$"
        }
    ]
}
```

My requirement is to show it in excel with column headers as the key and the values in rows like this:

| name | type | id | available | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| burger | saucy | 1 | true | 3$ |
| pizza | spicy | 2 | true | 2$ |

Comment: I assume you are referring to JSONConverter, why would you not want to use it? You also need to show your code attempt, a sample of your JSON file and the desired output on Excel.

Comment: It's even not clear what you are asking. How to get the JSON-data (is it from a web page? Do you call a web service? Do you have it already stored as a file?) or how to parse it? There is no build in function in VBA to parse it, basically it is string handling, but you need a deep understanding about how a JSON looks like, and you need to think about what you want to do with the extracted data. If you are *really* good at programming and have all the knowledge you need, you will end up with something similar to the JSONConverter - so why not use it?

Comment: Actually the data is a little sensitive so I can't use an external library like the VBA json and for the json file it's locally stored in my computer. So I had a question like how can we convert that json file into excel table using the VBA.

Comment: The library simply parse the JSON string into a collection of dictionaries so if you are still wary of it, I'm sure you can review the code to make sure it's not doing anything more than its purpose and potentially pose a security risk.. @Hemans19

Comment: Is there any other method that you are aware of?

Comment: @Hemans19 You can use Regex, or parse character by character using `Left` `Mid` `Right` functions which is really what JSONConverter does as well. If you only intend to pull few informations from the JSON String then Regex could work but you need to show a sample for us to help you

Comment: { "menu": "food",  "open": "true",  "order": "true", "food":[ {  "name": "burger",  "type": "saucy", "id":1, "available":true, price:"3$"}, {  "name": "pizza",  "type": "spicy", "id":2, "available":true, price:"2$"} ] } actually the json file looks like this, now my requirement is to show it in excel with column headers as the key and the values in row looks like this (eg:- burger, saucy,1, true,3$) @raymond WU

Comment: @Hemans19 Please edit your question and paste your JSON string in there.. And also a screenshot sample of the output you are expecting out of that JSON

Comment: I have edited the question and also a sample output I have added as I am not able to add images due to less number is stars.

Comment: All the pizza,burger details are in a new row in the excel.

Comment: You can post the link, we can add that in for you. Also your posted JSON looks wrong, why `price` has no quotes? @Hemans19

Comment: [Tim Hall's VBA-Json project](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
')  is completely open source. You can easily examine all the code and confirm it does not provide a security risk, and it works well.  But parsing a JSON is merely string manipulation, and can be done in native VBA code.  Of course, you could use regular expressions.  This, too, would require calling a library external to VBA (Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5) which does not have open source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Regex solution which only work specifically to your JSON, the key value in your JSON file must be exactly the same as what you have provided in the question.

Your posted JSON is invalid currently as `price` does not have quotes so please double check and use the correct regex pattern in the code below:

```
Private Sub ParseFoodJSON()
    Dim jsontxt As String
    jsontxt = OpenTxtFile("D:/TestJSON.txt") 'Change to your JSON file path
    
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Pattern = """name"":[\s]{0,}""([\w\d\s]{1,})"",[\s]{0,}""type"":[\s]{0,}""([\w\d\s]{1,})"",[\s]{0,}""id"":([\w\d\s]{1,}),[\s]{0,}""available"":([\w\d\s]{1,}),[\s]{0,}""price"":""([\w\d\s$]{1,})"""
    
    'Use below regex if your price key really does not have quotes
    'regex.Pattern = """name"":[\s]{0,}""([\w\d\s]{1,})"",[\s]{0,}""type"":[\s]{0,}""([\w\d\s]{1,})"",[\s]{0,}""id"":([\w\d\s]{1,}),[\s]{0,}""available"":([\w\d\s]{1,}),[\s]{0,}price:""([\w\d\s$]{1,})"""
    
    If regex.test(jsontxt) Then
        Dim regexColl As Object
        Set regexColl = regex.Execute(jsontxt)
        
        Dim foodArr() As Variant
        ReDim foodArr(1 To regexColl.Count + 1, 1 To 5) As Variant
                
        foodArr(1, 1) = "name"
        foodArr(1, 2) = "type"
        foodArr(1, 3) = "id"
        foodArr(1, 4) = "available"
        foodArr(1, 5) = "price"
        
        Dim i As Long
        Dim foodIndex As Long
        
        For i = 0 To regexColl.Count - 1
            foodIndex = i + 2
            foodArr(foodIndex, 1) = regexColl(i).SubMatches(0)
            foodArr(foodIndex, 2) = regexColl(i).SubMatches(1)
            foodArr(foodIndex, 3) = regexColl(i).SubMatches(2)
            foodArr(foodIndex, 4) = regexColl(i).SubMatches(3)
            foodArr(foodIndex, 5) = regexColl(i).SubMatches(4)
        Next i
    End If
    
    Set regexColl = Nothing
    Set regex = Nothing
        
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(foodArr, 1), UBound(foodArr, 2)).Value = foodArr
    
    Erase foodArr
End Sub

Private Function OpenTxtFile(argPath As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Dim txtFile As TextStream
    Set txtFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(argPath)
    
    OpenTxtFile = txtFile.ReadAll
    
    txtFile.Close
    Set txtFile = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Function
```

Running `ParseFoodJSON` will parse the JSON given in `OpenTxtFile` (the first line) and print the result in your `ActiveSheet` which you will need to change to suit your purpose.