# Check if a string is valid json string using VBA excel

Tags: json, excel, vba, string, github

I don't know the contents of JSON like the key-value pair so is there any method that we can use to know if the JSON string is valid or not using VBA excel.

The json looks like this

```json
{
    "menu": "food",
    "open": "true",
    "order": "true",
    "food": [
        {
            "name": "burger",
            "type": "saucy",
            "id": 1,
            "available": true,
            "price": "3$"
        },
        {
            "name": "pizza",
            "type": "spicy",
            "id": 2,
            "available": true,
            "price": "2$"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and parse your json file with [`VBA-tools/VBA-JSON`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

```vb
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456}}")
```

> JSON conversion and parsing for VBA (Windows and Mac Excel, Access, and other Office applications).
> It grew out of the excellent project [vba-json](https://code.google.com/archive/p/vba-json/), with additions and improvements made to resolve bugs and improve performance (as part of VBA-Web).

I understand from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69188119/6309) that you "don't want to use a GitHub project nor use Power Query but I am not able to get any proper reference on how to do it."

Here is a proper reference:

You can see it in action with "[Excel VBA: Parse JSON, Easily](https://medium.com/swlh/excel-vba-parse-json-easily-c2213f4d8e7a)" from [Daniel Ferry](https://twitter.com/excelheorw)

Comment: Actually can you please tell what is done by this function JsonConverter.ParseJson @VonC

Comment: I am trying to open the json through dialogue box in VBA but I am a little confused like how to access the json after the file location has been accessed by the vba program.

Comment: @Hemans19 You can see that function in https://medium.com/swlh/excel-vba-parse-json-easily-c2213f4d8e7a, and in https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/06b6c45a2e8086a7a761f00bead7460852d6b602/JsonConverter.bas#L164-L189.

Comment: @Hemans19 You would need to read a file and import its content into a string variable first: https://www.codevba.com/office/read_text_file_into_string_variable.htm#.YULkYJ1MR6s and https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

Comment: can you please tell like how to check if the json string formed after this is correct or not like syntactically.

Comment: can you please tell like how to check if the json string formed after parsing is correct or not like if the strings are formed have double quotes or not. @VonC

Comment: @Hemans19 As mentioned in https://medium.com/swlh/excel-vba-parse-json-easily-c2213f4d8e7a, you will get a runtime error if the json string is invalid.

Comment: Ya I am under getting a runtime error but actually I want that runtime error to display to the user as an error message box so is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: @Hemans19 I don't have much beside documentations like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/error-codes/elements-of-run-time-error-handling or https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/